# Django datetime fromisoformat: argument must be str

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Hi I had this error while try to running server. It may cause by the datetime field. Can someone check it for me.
[image]

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
    
    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now
        self.save()

    def approve_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approve_comment=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('mblog.Post', related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approve_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approve_comment = True
        self.save()
        
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

views.py

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = models.Post

def get_queryset(self):
    return models.Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone).order_by('-published_date')

class DraftListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'mblog/post_list.html'
    model = models.Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=True).order_by('created_date')
```

And had anyway better to set default for the DateTimeField?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: where is the error?

Comment: I just edit it. Can you check it again?

Comment: use `auto_now_add=True` instead of `default=timezone.now`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you also go through the udemy course, got the same error myself.
Probably not relevant to you anymore, but if someone else had the same problem, it's just a case of adding parenthesis () after `timezone.now` in `Post` class in `publish` method

so it looks like this:

```
def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()
```